# How do i call any procedure or function inside initialization block of any unit in DELPHI

Tags: delphi, initialization, pascal

I am trying to call a procedure in initialization block of my unit, as i want that procedure to execute at the starting of the application, before anything else.
Compiler shows this error:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(152): E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods or constructor
```

This is what my procedure looks like

```
procedure TForm2.initilize()   ;
      begin
  ListBox2.Items.Add('Mohit');
  ListBox2.Items.Add('Raghav');
  ListBox2.Items.Add('Maninder');
  ListBox2.Items.Add('Tanya');
      end;
```

and this is where calling is being done in initialization

```
initialization
begin
     TForm2.initilize();
end;
```

Comment: You can't add items to the list box before the list box is created. OnCreate of the form is where you'd do that. Regardless, the error message is saying that you need 'initialize' to be a class method. But making it so won't help because a class method does not have access to an instance of the class (think of your scenario, there's no instance yet).

Comment: You certainly don't want to do this in unit initialization

Comment: The code you've provided should be in the form's `OnCreate` event, or the items should be added to the listbox using the Object Inspector at designtime. What you're attempting is never going to work, because you can't add items to a listbox that does not exist before the form is created. Even if you're auto-creating the form, `initialization` would run before that form is created, which means the form still will not exist. You're also trying to add to the form class itself, not an instance of the form, which (again) will never work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the classic **constructor**. The advantage is that you can use the same method even for frames, becaus of frames do not have OnCreate.

```
interface
...
type
TForm2 = class(TForm)
private
  procedure initialize;
  ...
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  ...
end;

implementation

constructor TForm2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  initialize;
end;
```